# Traktor Audio 6 Soundcard recognized, but not selectable

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I got a Native Instruments Traktor Audio 6 Soundcard via USB plugged in and it is working so far in Mixxx.

[Mixxx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILdon.png)

In pavucontrol however, it is recognized in Configuration ("Konfiguration"), but not in Outputs ("Lautstärkegeräte")

[pavucontrol configuration and outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEfZ0.png)

i cannot select it via the gnome audio applet either, i does not show up.

Any ideas how to fix this? i would like to use the sound card as a default sound card for everyday activity on my system.

Comment: From what I've heard, PA might get confused if your card's channel do not find into the standard 5.1 schema. Try [setting channel_map](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wie-pulseaudio-aus-ibex-8.10-entfernen/2/#post-1663491).

Comment: Found help on a german forum: (https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/traktor-audio-6-erkannt-aber-nicht-anwaehlbar/3/#post-8759808).

In short i had to edit /lib/udev/rules.d/90-pulseaudio.rules.

When plugged-in, the soundcard was given a different idProduct than expected (1011 instead of 1010). 
'[ 3340.675825] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1010'.

Changed 1011 to 1010 via 90-pulseaudio.rules and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I've just accepted this as broken for years and worked around it by using my on board sound in Ubuntu with a mixer (I dual boot for music production) but your fix has worked for me - thank you! :)

Comment: THANK YOU for this solution!!!! Changing the pulseaudio.rules from 1011 to 1010 fixed it. I had spent two whole days working my way around alsa, pulseaudio, dual boot settings, usb... I can now get back to work :)